# Why does the Rust compiler not use the expected trait implementation once I add an implementation for Vec<T>?

Tags: rust, traits

I'm trying to implement a reader which could be able to extract values from different types from a file. There is a `File` struct which represents the file resource (and methods to access its content), and a `Reader` trait which makes it possible to extract values based on the resulting type. The (dummy) implementation looks like this ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=859160ad8016cafc2ce07c7e6b724fe7&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)):

```
use std::io::Result;

mod file {
    use std::io::Result;

    pub struct File {/* ... */}

    pub trait Reader<T> {
        fn read(&mut self) -> Result<T>;
    }

    impl Reader<u32> for File {
        fn read(&mut self) -> Result<u32> {
            // Dummy implementation
            Ok(10)
        }
    }

    impl Reader<u8> for File {
        fn read(&mut self) -> Result<u8> {
            // Dummy implementation
            Ok(0)
        }
    }

    impl Reader<bool> for File {
        fn read(&mut self) -> Result<bool> {
            // Dummy implementation
            Ok(false)
        }
    }
}

use file::{File, Reader};

impl<T: Default> Reader<Vec<T>> for File
where
    File: Reader<T> + Reader<u32>,
{
    fn read(&mut self) -> Result<Vec<T>> {
        let count: u32 = self.read()?;
        let mut array: Vec<T> = Vec::with_capacity(count as usize);
        for _ in 0..count {
            let mut item: T = self.read()?;
            array.push(item);
        }

        Ok(array)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut file = File {};
    let _v: Vec<u8> = file.read().unwrap();
}
```

Everything worked until I added the `Reader<Vec<T>>` implementation. Vectors are stored in the file as a `u32` indicating the number of elements followed by the element's representation. The compiler gives the following error:

```
error[E0308]: try expression alternatives have incompatible types
  --> src/main.rs:41:26
   |
41 |         let count: u32 = self.read()?;
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                          |
   |                          expected u32, found type parameter
   |                          help: try wrapping with a success variant: `Ok(self.read()?)`
   |
   = note: expected type `u32`
              found type `T`
```

Even though I specified that `File` implements both `Reader<T>` and `Reader<u32>`, it seems to be stuck on `Reader<T>`.

What's even more strange is that if I only keep 2 implementations of the `Reader` trait (removing `Reader<bool>` for instance), the code compiles without any issue ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0b4ead500802fcd4662413ac4ef340ea&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)).

Why can't the compiler find out it should use the `Reader<u32>` implementation for `count` initialization? What should I change?

I've found a workaround, but I'm still interested in understanding why the compiler can't figure it out automatically:

```
let count: u32 = (self as &mut Reader<u32>).read()?;
```

---

Issue has been reported as [rust-lang/rust#54344](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54344).

Comment: I think you should report this as a bug.

Comment: "But I'm still interested in understanding why the compiler can't figure that out automatically." black magic use a lot of mana so maybe it's run out of it.

Comment: @Stargateur I feel like the compiler should be able to figure this out. The `T` in the result is the same as the `T` parameter to the type and it is not possible for a different implementation to have the same return type.

Comment: @PeterHall I guess I will, thanks.

Comment: @Tey' link it here (or in the [SO Rust chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62927/rust)) when you've made the report.

Comment: Funny thing is that if you remove the `impl Reader<bool> for File` it works!

Comment: FWIW, you can write your `Vec<T>` implementation more idiomatically (and equally efficiently) as `std::iter::repeat_with(|| self.read()).take(count as usize).collect()`. You can collect to a `Result<Vec<T>>`.

Comment: I've reported it as an issue and added a reference to it in the question.
@Shepmaster Thanks for the tip, but since `read()` returns a `Result`, handling errors would make the code less readable IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

There's no good reason why the compiler can't figure out that it should use the `Reader<u32>` implementation for `let count: u32 = ...`. It's a compiler bug because `T` has no connection to how `self.read()` is being used on that line. The return type of one `.read()` call seems to be determining the return type of another `.read()` call when it shouldn't be!

Additionally, if it were not a bug, then it wouldn't make a difference what implementations of `Reader<T>` there are other than `Reader<u8>` and `Reader<u32>`, but as @rodrigo pointed out, the presence of a `Reader<bool>` implementation triggers this error.

Note that the `?` (which is equivalent to the `match` shown below) has nothing to do with the bug, since you still get the error when the `Result<u32>` is gotten directly:

```
let count_result: Result<u32> = self.read(); // error happens here
let count: u32 = match count_result {
    std::result::Result::Ok(val) => val,
    std::result::Result::Err(err) => {
        return std::result::Result::Err(std::convert::From::from(err))
    }
};
```

Comment: *It's a compiler bug* — please link to the associated bug report for future reference.

Comment: What does `?` become, then?

Comment: `try!` can be [seen since it's a macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/macros.rs.html#299-307). `?` is lowered into invocations of the [`Try` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Try.html). For example, `try!` does not work with `Option` while `?` does.

Comment: @Shepmaster as for the bug report, I searched the rust-lang/rust issues and didn't find anything. I don't think anybody's reported it yet.

Comment: @AaronMiller Thanks for your answer, I've upvoted it for the effort and the fact that it reminded me to report the issue in rust-lang/rust (which I've just done). However, I'm not sure I can accept it as a solution since the bug reason has already been given in comments by someone else (and there's no solution if it's a compiler bug anyway).

Comment: @Tey' *has already been given in comments by someone else* — that's meaningless here on Stack Overflow. Comments are considered extremely ephemeral and they can be deleted at any time. If the author of those comments wanted to take the time to provide an answer, they could have (and still can). You are of course welcome to continue to not accept an answer, but "because someone said it in a comment" isn't something that Stack Overflow participants care about.